# how print multipage with angularprint?

Tags: angularjs, printing

I'm using AngularPrint to print html table.
But I can print only what I see on the screen.

I tried to use page-break but nothing change (FireFox and Chrome)

Can you you show me a example ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I use print pdf rest service.
angualar-print doesn't supply excepted result.
thx

Answer (score 0):

You need to have everything you want to print in the DOM at the moment you press the print button.
That means if you don't want to see everything you want to print, you still need to have it in the HTML code but hide for media="screen".
It looks like the angular-print module provides a directive for that:

```
  <div print-only>
    I'll print, but until then nobody wants me
    <p>Me, too!</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: I want print entire table, not only a part. I have added print-section tag on table. The problem is that my table is too big and angularprint print only visible table